# How can I add a repository if it does not have release files file for my version?

Tags: ppa, repository

I am trying to download `uget download manager` on my Ubuntu 22.10, and on official website it says to add repository `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable` but when I run this command it says

```
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu kinetic Release' does
   not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is there any way I can add this repository?

Same thing happens when I try to install it's browser extension with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uget-team/ppa`

```
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release' does
   not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Did you look at what it supports?  ie. https://launchpad.net/~plushuang-tw/+archive/ubuntu/uget-stable   Unless your purpose is to explore a corrupted/damaged & subsequently *hacked* system - I'd stay away from it.  Go get the source code  & build it for yourself; that will be safer  (you can put it in your own PPA or *personal package archive* too if & build for multiple releases if you need)

Comment: The software in that repository supports up to 18.04 (well ... 18.10 if you really want something unsupported). If you *really* want that software, you'll need to either install 18.04 on your system or use a virtual machine 

Answer (score 1):

If a PPA doesn't have packages for your release it is a very bad idea to "add" it. This action can break your system.

You can download and try to install deb files from an old PPA, but in most cases they won't install because of wrong dependencies.